# Highlighting the admin comment username

Tags: wordpress, comments, admin, highlighting

Hi I'm currently looking into highlighting my comments, I found a tutorial that has allowed me to add a background color. But I'm looking around to see how I could get an Author tag or Admin tag next to my name.

Example: Antony (Author)

Comment: Are you sure that's a programming question?

Comment: Well I think it is, I know highlighting comments is due to css. But I'm trying to figure out how I can just get Author or an Admin tag next to my name. I would imagine I need to edit the comments.php but I'm not entirely sure. So hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the author name by putting,

the_author()

this code in the place where ever you want to display the author.

for example,

the auther is

php the_author();

Comment: That doesn't answer his question at all... have you even read it?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if comment user id and post author id are same and add text appropriately.

```
if($comment->user_id == $post->post_author) {
    $author_text = ' (author)';
} else {
    $author_text ='';
}
```

Here is how you can do it for Twenty Eleven Theme.

Change

```
                /* translators: 1: comment author, 2: date and time */
                printf( __( '%1$s on %2$s <span class="says">said:</span>', 'twentyeleven' ),
                    sprintf( '<span class="fn">%s</span>', get_comment_author_link() ),
                    sprintf( '<a href="%1$s"><time pubdate datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a>',
                        esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),
                        get_comment_time( 'c' ),
                        /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                        sprintf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'twentyeleven' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() )
                    )
                );
```

To

```
                // Check if comment user id and post author id are same.
                if($comment->user_id == $post->post_author) {
                    $author_text = ' (author)';
                } else {
                    $author_text ='';
                }
                /* translators: 1: comment author, 2: is author?, 3: date and time */
                printf( __( '%1$s%2s on %3$s <span class="says">said:</span>', 'twentyeleven' ),
                    sprintf( '<span class="fn">%s</span>', get_comment_author_link() ),
                    $author_text,
                    sprintf( '<a href="%1$s"><time pubdate datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a>',
                        esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),
                        get_comment_time( 'c' ),
                        /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                        sprintf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'twentyeleven' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() )
                    )
                );
```

You can use this as base and edit your theme accordingly.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, just wondering if this works in the callback comment function? I'm using different code to the one you provided from the TwentyEleven theme.

Comment: Yes, you will have to edit the callback comment function to add this condition.